# Apache Flink error while trying to run a job from a jar - Can't find the main(String[])

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink

I'm having an error with Apache Flink. I built the jar for the project from Eclipse both through maven install feature and mvn clean package(using aven-assembly-plugin dependency). I tried to run the command ./bin/flink run -c tbdm.kafka_flink_integration.Flink_Kafka_Receiver_Sender ./flink-kafka.jar from the main flink folder, but then this error occurs:

The program finished with the following exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[]) method from the class tbdm.kafka_flink_integration.Flink_Kafka_Receiver_Sender: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:315) and so on...`

I'm using flink 1.16.1 and all the dependencies for flink are 1.16.1. I also tried to fix following the similar already existing topics,but i did not manage to do it.
I used Java to build the code

This is my main java class which gets data from kafka topic, capitalize it and store it to a mongodb database:

```
`package tbdm.kafka_flink_integration;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
//import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
//import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.bson.Document;


public class Flink_Kafka_Receiver_Sender {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = new DB(mongoClient, "testdb");
            System.out.println("Connected do MongoDB");
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }*/
        String inputTopic = "flink_input";
        String outputTopic = "flink_output";
        String server = "localhost:9092";
        StreamStringOperation(server, inputTopic, outputTopic);
    }
    
    public static void StreamStringOperation(String server, String inputTopic, String outputTopic) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", server);

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(inputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
        FlinkKafkaProducer<String> flinkKafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(server, outputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema());

        DataStream<String> stringInputStream = environment.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);
        stringInputStream.map(new StringCapitalizer()).addSink(flinkKafkaProducer);
        environment.execute();
    }

    
    public static class StringCapitalizer implements MapFunction<String, String> {
        @Override
        public String map(String data) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(data.toUpperCase());
            // Creazione della connessione al database
            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDatabase");
            
            // Selezione della collection su cui effettuare l'operazione di inserimento
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
            
            // Creazione di un documento da inserire nel database
            Document document = new Document();
            document.append("stringa", data.toUpperCase());
            
            // Inserimento del documento nella collection
            collection.insertOne(document);
            return data.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    public static void StreamConsumer(String inputTopic, String server) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", server);

        
        DataStream<String> stringInputStream = environment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(inputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props));

        stringInputStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -999736771747691234L;

            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Receiving from Kafka : " + value;
            }
        }).print();

        environment.execute();
    }
    
    public static FlinkKafkaProducer<String> createStringProducer(String output_topic, String kafkaAddress) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);

        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<String>(output_topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
    }
    
}`
```

And this is the pom.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>tbdm</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-flink-integration</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>kafka-flink-integration</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.12</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                 <mainClass>tbdm.kafka_flink_integration.Flink_Kafka_Receiver_Sender</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>`
```

The program works if run on eclipse itself, but can't run the jar on flink

I'm running Apache Flink in the same local machine (ubuntu), so i can also access to the gui dashboard by accessing the localhost:8081 page, but i can't even load the jar from there.

Comment: Can You paste the whole pom? Seems that You just pasted part of it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Now the pom is complete

Comment: I don't think `flink-connector-kafka` should be `provided` btw.

Comment: Have you tried using the maven template given in the docs? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/configuration/maven/#template-for-creating-an-uberfat-jar-with-dependencies